# Facebook Graph API: /id/picture returns "Invalid response"

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook application that has been retrieving pictures using the guidance found here: [Using Pictures](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/)

This has been working up until recently, where now if I retrieve an item picture using the following:

```
/<id>/picture
```

I get this response:

```
{
   "error": "Invalid response"
}
```

Is this a known issue?  This has been working up until around this week.

Comment: Debug the `<id>`, is that correct?

Comment: The id is a placeholder for the id of a Facebook API Graph object.  Any object id that I use returns the invalid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `picture`, you should use `profile_picture` if you want the **URL** of the pic, just like-

```
<ID>?fields=profile_picture
```

[Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=Shadowfax.sahil%3Ffields%3Dprofile_picture)

And if you want to use the image directly you can use:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<ID>/picture
```

Example: http://graph.facebook.com/Shadowfax.sahil/picture

Comment: I tried editing the main post, but it won't let me post more than two links.  Frustrating.  Please visit this URL: https://graph.facebook.com/331218348435/picture  and then this one: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=331218348435%2Fpicture

The latter returns the invalid response.

Comment: You didn't got me. See, you can request for `ID/picture` to the graph API BUT for `/ID?fields=picture`. Why didnt you tried first example? `/picture` could be used as a direct source of the image- not for the API call. - hope you got this time

Comment: Ah yes, you are right in that using ?fields=picture works.  However, <id>/picture has been working up until recently and my code that has been working for months suddenly stopped working as designed this week.  I have been requesting id/picture from the graph API without any problems until this week.  I am currently falling back to fields=picture, but the documentation provided at the link in my original post seems to assert that I should be able to poll the Facebook Graph API using <id>/picture (and as I have done successfully for many months now).  Thank you for your continued assistance. :)

Comment: Looks like I need a reputation of 15+ to do that. Boo.  Oh well, thank you for helping!

Comment: Oh I see... that checkmark needs to be *above* the voting.  You know, for us newbs. ;)  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `/ID?fields=picture` does not help when you'd like to get an arbitrarily large image. I have experienced `Invalid Response` when calling `/ID/picture` in the Graph API and found a solution that fixes it.

Try `/ID/picture?redirect=false&width=800`. The `redirect=false` option seems to fix the problem with invalid response from the API.